# No access to /dev/mem. Try runnig as root!

Tags: raspberry-pi, root

I'm using ubuntu 22.04 on raspberry. I'm trying gpio pins. But I couldn't access to gpio pins without being root. I got this error,No access to /dev/mem. Try runnig as root! How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This is not really a robotics-specific question. I suggest you do a web search for `raspberry pi gpio linux`.